# If salt loses its flavor, how can you season it?

Tags: flavor, salt

I have a shaker of salt on my table, and (fingers crossed) it still tastes salty. But I'm concerned that someday it will lose its saltiness and then I wouldn't know what to do.

Is there something you can add to salt that will make it "saltier"? Are there things that are saltier than salt? Or things that taste salty for a different reason, so, eg if someone loses their salt-tasting taste-buds they could still detect something as salty?

Answer (score 13):

Salt is not a herb or a spice that loses its specific properties over time. It's a mineral and is salty since millions of years. It will still be salty if you're already gone.

No need to worry here! It will be salty long enough.